# Inserting values into a column when Table1 column A value matches Table 2 Column B Value

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables **ImportData** and **PurchaseInfo**. I am trying to import *[Supplier Contact Name]* from **ImportData** to **PurchaseInfo**, when *[SupplierName] in **ImportData** = *[SupplierName] in **PurchaseInfo**

This is the query I tried:

```
INSERT INTO PurchaseInfo ([Supplier Contact Name]) 
SELECT [Supplier Contact Name] 
FROM ImportData 
WHERE PurchaseInfo.[Supplier Name] = SupplierInfo.SupplierName
```

I get the error

```
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The multi-part identifier "PurchaseInfo.Supplier Name" could not be bound.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Table schema]

Comment: Can you post the schema of PurchaseInfo as well?

Comment: You seem to want to do an update, not insert

Comment: Yup.. looks like you need to do an UPDATE and not an INSERT here...  You basically want to populate the SupplierContactName in the PurchaseInfo table where the SupplierName is present in the PurchaseInfo table right?  Take a look at the statement in my answer

Comment: Ugh... column names with spaces in them...

Answer (score 1):

Taking a guess that Vinny wishes to update the `PurchaseInfo` table, and that `SupplierInfo` is same as `ImportData`

```
UPDATE PurchaseInfo 
SET [Supplier Contact Name] = S.[Supplier Contact Name]
FROM ImportData I JOIN PurchaseInfo PI ON PI.[Supplier Name] = I.SupplierName
```